# Getting data from metaweather API to angularjs page

Tags: angularjs, api, weather-api

I'm building a simple weather app that gets the weather for any city.
For this API there are two stages:
1) you enter a name of a city, get its "where on earth ID" (woeid).
2) use the woeid to search for the weather.

This is the API: https://www.metaweather.com/api/

For example: 
https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=london
You get this JSON:
[{"title":"London","location_type":"City","woeid":44418,"latt_long":"51.506321,-0.12714"}]

For starters, just to get the woeid would be great.
It fails to connect to the API but when i type it manually it works.

**app.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('weatherApp', []);
app.controller('weatherCtrl', ['$scope', 'weatherService', function($scope, weatherService) {
function fetchWoeid(city) {
    weatherService.getWoeid(city).then(function(data){
        $scope.place = data;
    });
}

fetchWoeid('london');

$scope.findWoeid = function(city) {
    $scope.place = '';
    fetchWoeid(city);
};
}]);

app.factory('weatherService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q){
function getWoeid (city) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=' + city)
        .success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(err){
            console.log('Error retrieving woeid');
            deferred.reject(err);
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}

return {
    getWoeid: getWoeid
};
}]);
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="weatherApp">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Weather App</title>
<link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="weatherCtrl">
<form>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="city" placeholder="e.g. london" />
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="findWoeid(city)" />
</div>
</form>
<p ng-show="city">Searching the forecasts for: {{city}}</p>
<div>
<h1>WOEID is: {{ place }}</h1>
<a ng-click="findWeather('london'); city = ''">reset</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are having a Cross Origin problem. It doesn't look like Metaweather supports JSONP, so the fix for this is a bit more complex. You need to be running your page through a server that can support a proxy. One such example is https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors-anywhere. If you set that up using the defaults then change your AJAX call to:

`$http.get('http://localhost:8080/https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=' + city)`

Comment: I will try this. Thanks